# How to vibrate CCSprite in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Can anyone tell me how to vibrate/shake CCSprite in cocos2d???plz give me some example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the object is static you could create a `CCSequence` of `MoveTo` actions - pixel or two to the one side and pixel to the other of the real position and repeat it with `CCRepeat` how many times you need or use `CCRepeatForever` and remove action by tag with `CCActionManager` method `removeActionByTag:(int)tag target:(id)target` when some event occur.